# Why is my label in a custom collection view cell causing an error?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add a label that will be the header of each cell in my Collection View.  To do this, I added the label to the cell in storyboard (the cell is hooked up to a custom `UITableViewCell` class called `ListCell`).  I added an IBOutlet for the label in this custom cell class `ListCell`.  It works perfectly (i.e. no errors but still no label) until when I add the line to change the text of the label I call `globe` I get

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and it points to the line where I try to change the text so I'm not sure what optional it is talking about?  The custom cell class has just the outlet for the label.  Here is the code for the function with the line that crashes it:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ListCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 48.0/255.0, green: 62.0/255.0, blue: 96.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cell.globe.text = "Header"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint right before the offending line of code and check to see if `globe` is nil.

Comment: Initialise your label inside the init method of ListCell class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have also

1. created a label in interface builder
2. hooked up the label to your outlet correctly

If you skipped any of the above, you will get the error as described because the declaration

```
@IBOutlet weak var globe : UILabel!
```

will cause the failure to unwrap a `nil` label when it is first accessed.

Comment: I made sure I did the above correctly and I am still getting the same error